# Find out schema of the table

Tags: sql, r

Im connected to database and when i do this query:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
```

I get a list:

```
       table_name
1      dt_2019
2      dt_2020
```

But i want to find out the schema where table "dt_2019" is, so i can make this query:

```
SELECT dt_2019 FROM schema_that_i_don't_know
```

and desired result will be that table dt_2019

How could i do that?

Comment: Are you sure `dt_2019` is NOT a table in the database? could you try `select * from dt_2019 limit 5;` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring when you say *"find out the schema"* you mean catalog, schema, name, etc ... there's another meta table you can often use. In SQL Server, at least, there's:

```r
# con <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
str(DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "
  select *
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_name = 'r2test'"))
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  23 variables:
#  $ TABLE_CATALOG           : chr  "mydb" "mydb" "mydb"
#  $ TABLE_SCHEMA            : chr  "db_owner" "db_owner" "db_owner"
#  $ TABLE_NAME              : chr  "r2test" "r2test" "r2test"
#  $ COLUMN_NAME             : chr  "a" "b" "c"
#  $ ORDINAL_POSITION        : int  1 2 3
#  $ COLUMN_DEFAULT          : chr  NA NA NA
#  $ IS_NULLABLE             : chr  "YES" "YES" "YES"
#  $ DATA_TYPE               : chr  "int" "nvarchar" "real"
#  $ CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: int  NA -1 NA
#  $ CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH  : int  NA -1 NA
#  $ NUMERIC_PRECISION       : int  10 NA 24
#  $ NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX : int  10 NA 2
#  $ NUMERIC_SCALE           : int  0 NA NA
#  $ DATETIME_PRECISION      : int  NA NA NA
#  $ CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG   : chr  NA NA NA
#  $ CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA    : chr  NA NA NA
#  $ CHARACTER_SET_NAME      : chr  NA "UNICODE" NA
#  $ COLLATION_CATALOG       : chr  NA NA NA
#  $ COLLATION_SCHEMA        : chr  NA NA NA
#  $ COLLATION_NAME          : chr  NA "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" NA
#  $ DOMAIN_CATALOG          : chr  NA NA NA
#  $ DOMAIN_SCHEMA           : chr  NA NA NA
#  $ DOMAIN_NAME             : chr  NA NA NA
```